# cannot get full output on randomize choice code

Tags: python

When I run this below program, the output that I get is in single letter

```python
import random

names = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")

person_who_will_pay = random.choice(names)
print(person_who_will_pay)
print(person_who_will_pay + " is going to buy the meal today")
```

sample input:

> ben, joe, catty, elf

output:

> b is going to pay the meal

Sometimes the program doesn't count the names I've given.

`Debug rolet.py` gives me the names of all, separated by a comma:

> jame, rom, dot, recis going to buy the meal today

The output should be a complete name which I provide as input.

Comment: (1) You have to `split` the entered string by comma. Then make choice from the received list. (2) How is this question related to PHP?

Comment: I suggested removing the PHP tag, I think it's a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Input function returns a string. To get it to a list, you need to apply the string method .split() to it:

```py
import random

names = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")
# names is a String. To get each element, you need to split the
# string based using commas as the argument:
name_list = names.split(',')
person_who_will_pay = random.choice(name_list)
print(person_who_will_pay + " is going to buy the meal today")
```